# SVG image with stroke is cropping

Tags: svg, width, crop, stroke

I have simple image

```
<symbol id="cloud" viewBox="0 0 96 96">
    <path style="stroke:#356e94; 
stroke-width:2px;" d="M 44 12 C 29.707031 12 17.828125 21.632813 13.75 34.625 C 5.71875 38.5 0 46.507813 0 56 C 0 69.207031 10.789063 80 24 80 L 72 80 C 85.210938 80 96 69.207031 96 56 C 96 43.273438 85.921875 33 73.375 32.25 C 68.640625 20.480469 57.421875 12 44 12 Z M 44 20 C 54.945313 20 64.082031 27.296875 67 37.25 L 67.875 40.25 L 71.125 40.125 C 71.984375 40.070313 72.234375 40 72 40 C 80.886719 40 88 47.113281 88 56 C 88 64.882813 80.886719 72 72 72 L 24 72 C 15.113281 72 8 64.882813 8 56 C 8 49.164063 12.253906 43.441406 18.25 41.125 L 20.25 40.375 L 20.75 38.375 C 23.300781 27.871094 32.664063 20 44 20 Z M 44 33 L 33 48 L 40 48 L 40 64 L 48 64 L 48 48 L 55 48 Z "/>
</symbol>
```

But when am using **`stroke:#356e94;`** 
    `stroke-width:2px;` my image in html is cropping how to avoid this?

Comment: By making the viewbox bigger?

Answer (score 3):

You can use overflow attribute (from css).

```
<symbol id="cloud" viewBox="0 0 96 96" overflow="visible" style="overflow: visible;">
    <path style="stroke:#356e94; 
stroke-width:2px;" d="..."/>
</symbol>
```

I use both - overflow attribute directly in the element and overflow in style because of different support in different browsers.

**UPDATE**

Example: https://fiddle.jshell.net/zjsw0jtn/1/

Comment: same result ( the image is cropping

Comment: I updated my answer with example. First shape is without overflow and the stroke is cut the second is correct (with overflow settings)

Comment: I got it. Thank u) any way its works only from svg file not by css(

Comment: CSS overflow works only in some browsers (that's why I wrote I use both settings). For example this: https://fiddle.jshell.net/zjsw0jtn/3/ - there are 3 shapes: 1st without overflow, 2nd with overflow attribute in SVG, 3rd with CSS overflow. In Chrome, you can see 2nd and 3rd correctly. In Mozilla, only 2nd is ok. So I suggest you to adjust the SVG. If you can't change the SVG directly, you can always adjust it in browser with JavaScript. Just parse the source and add the overflow attribute to symbol element.

Comment: Added `overflow: visible;` in `<symbol>` & `<svg>` element as a style and it worked in Firefox (which is where it was getting cropped for me). Thanks!